# String value coming with two double quoted to .ts

Tags: angular

If I given the normal value say hello in input field, it is coming like "hello", And if I have given the value like "hello", it is storing like ""hello"" . How to identify this two double quoted string and make it to one double quote .?

Comment: Can you please put a code snippet? It would be easy to understand your concern.

Comment: It is just the html reactive form, where as if I enter the text without any double quote , am getting like double quote text ("hello") which is fine.. where as If i enter the value with double string in input field, am getting like with two double quoted string (""hello"") which is to be identified and change to one double quoted string

Answer (score 2):

Use `str.replace(/"/g, '')` and wrap your string with artificial quotes. Something like

```
function stripQuotes(str) {
    let stripped = str.replace(/"/g, '');
    return '"'+stripped+'"';
}
```

Now calling `stripQuotes(""Hello"")` will return `"Hello"`, your desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Without code, it is impossible to predict why the input field is adding double quotes to the value.

However, if you are using typescript or javascript, you can use the following to rectify the 2-double quotes issue:

```
let str = '""hello""';
if(str.startsWith("\"\"") && str.endsWith("\"\"")){
    str = str.substr(1,str.length-2);
  // str = str.replace(/\"\"/g, "\""); //Alternatively you can use this, if there will not be 2-double quotes in between your string
}
store(str);
```